# How do I make a bar-chart in SVG have animated bars growing upwards?

Tags: svg

I am making a bar-chart as an SVG and would very much like my bars to be animated and grow upwards from "0" on the y-axis to their corresponding value.

What's making me struggle is that the coord (0,0) is at the top left and not at the bottom left. In my "non-animated" solution I was giving the bars different values of "y" depending on how high they were supposed to be, like this:

```
<svg id="graph" 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <linearGradient x1="0%" x2="0%" y1="10%" y2="100%" id="gradient">
        <stop style="stop-color:#0000FF" offset="0"></stop>
        <stop style="stop-color:#FFFFFF" offset="1"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <rect width="50" height="14" x="0" y="8" fill="url(#gradient)"></rect>
    <rect width="50" height="22" x="55" y="0" fill="url(#gradient)"></rect>
    <rect width="50" height="15" x="110" y="7" fill="url(#gradient)"></rect>
    <rect width="50" height="9" x="165" y="13" fill="url(#gradient)"></rect>
</svg>
```

This looks like a bar-chart because (y + height) is the same for all rectangles, but it's conceptually drawn "top to down" starting at different points of the y-axis and growing down to the same value of y.

Now when I want to animate this, I obviously want them to grow "upwards" and this is where I am stuck.

```
<rect width="50" height="14" x="0" y="8" fill="url(#gradient)">
    <animate attributeName="height" from="0" to="14" dur="2s" id="animation"></animate>    
</rect>
```

This will make the rectangle grow "down" from y=8 to y=22 and in a grid where (0,0) is on the top left that makes perfect sense. However, I really wanted to do the opposite and since it seems negative values for the "height" attribute is treated as 0 (or I could have animated the height from -14 to 0) I am unsure about how I would do that.

I've tried googling around but have not had much luck. I'd also like very much to do this without using a charting-library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wrap everything with a scale(1, -1) transformation all the y values are multiplied by -1, which has the effect of flipping the y-axis. You then need to translate everything down so they have a positive value and you can see them:

```
<g transform="translate(0, 40) scale(1, -1)">    
  <rect width="50" height="14" x="0" y="0" fill="url(#gradient)">
    <animate attributeName="height" from="0" to="14" dur="2s" fill="freeze"></animate>    
  </rect>
  <rect width="50" height="14" x="55" y="0" fill="url(#gradient)">
    <animate attributeName="height" from="0" to="22" dur="2s" fill="freeze"></animate>    
  </rect>
  <rect width="50" height="14" x="110" y="0" fill="url(#gradient)">
    <animate attributeName="height" from="0" to="15" dur="2s" fill="freeze"></animate>    
  </rect>
  <rect width="50" height="14" x="165" y="0" fill="url(#gradient)">
    <animate attributeName="height" from="0" to="9" dur="2s" fill="freeze"></animate>
  </rect>
</g>
```

Note that you need to set all the y values to be equal and you may want to flip the gradient.

Comment: Thanks! That solves my problem (though it made placing text overlays pretty awkward). I'm accepting this answer though, as I never mentioned text overlays in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution, without flipping any axes:

```
<svg id="graph" 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> 
    <linearGradient x1="0%" x2="0%" y1="10%" y2="100%" id="gradient">
        <stop style="stop-color:#0000FF" offset="0"></stop>
        <stop style="stop-color:#FFFFFF" offset="1"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <rect width="50" height="9" x="0" y="9" fill="url(#gradient)"></rect>
    <rect fill="white" opacity="1" x="-1" y="8" width="52">
        <animate attributeName="height" to="0" from="10" dur="2s" id="curtain"></animate>
    </rect>

    ...

</svg>
```

By drawing a solid bar and then adding a white non-transparent rectangle on top of it and having **that** rectangle get an animation it appears as if the bars are growing upwards.

I've ended up with this solution because I also need to add various labels and text overlays (but I left that part out of the question since I didn't think it was relevant). Flipping the svg with scale(1 -1) makes the text appear upside-down, and flipping just the part of the svg that has the bars in it means having to work with two different sets of coordinates which was making my code (this is a generated chart and not static XML) a bit messy.

Comment: Another option would be to add two animations to each rect: `<rect width="50" height="30" x="20" y="10" fill="url(#gradient)">
        <animate attributeName="height" to="30" from="0" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
        <animate attributeName="y" to="10" from="40" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
    </rect>`

Comment: Animating the y property, nice. Didn't think of that. I'll give it a shot as well and see which one ends up with the cleanest code (I'm generating these bars in the browser using Javascript).

Answer (score -1):

I played around with your code and changed some things.
What do you think about the following?

```
<svg id="graph" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <linearGradient x1="0%" x2="0%" y1="10%" y2="100%" id="gradient">
        <stop style="stop-color:#0000FF" offset="0"></stop>
        <stop style="stop-color:#FFFFFF" offset="1"></stop>
    </linearGradient>

    <rect width="50" height="14" x="0" y="8" xfill="url(#gradient)">
        <animate attributeName="height" from="0" to="14" dur="2s" id="animation1"></animate>    
    </rect>

    <rect width="50" height="22" x="55" y="0" xfill="url(#gradient)">
        <animate attributeName="height" from="0" to="14" dur="2s" id="animation2"></animate>    
    </rect>

    <rect width="50" height="15" x="110" y="7" xfill="url(#gradient)">
        <animate attributeName="height" from="0" to="14" dur="2s" id="animation3"></animate>    
    </rect>

    <rect width="50" height="9" x="165" y="13" xfill="url(#gradient)">
        <animate attributeName="height" from="0" to="14" dur="2s" id="animation"></animate>    
    </rect>

    <rect width="50" height="14" x="0" y="8" fill="url(#gradient)">
        <animate attributeName="height" from="0" to="14" dur="2s" id="animation4"></animate>    
    </rect>
</svg>
```

All the best

Comment: I think it looks fairly similar, was that a wrong copypaste or did I miss something?

Comment: Seems Safari is handling this different than Chrome/Firefox then. I'll look into it.

Comment: You've multiple elements with the same id. Although that's not causing a problem here, it isn't valid.

Comment: Unable to get Safari running on my laptop so can't test this, but I think it's wierd that it would work as that would indicate a very strange implementation of the SVG standard in Safari. Just to reiterate: I need the bar-animation to have the bars grow bottom-up and not top-down.